PHP compare floats and print +/- before difference prints both + and -
After reading about comparing float numbers, I wrote the following comparison:
$profitMarginPercent = (($clientTotal - $vendorTotal)/$vendorTotal) * 100;

if(abs($clientTotal - $vendorTotal) > PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON) {
    $profitMarginPercent = "+".round($profitMarginPercent, 2);
}
elseif(abs($clientTotal - $vendorTotal) < PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON) {
    $profitMarginPercent = "-".round($profitMarginPercent, 2);
}
elseif(abs($clientTotal - $vendorTotal) == PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON) {
    $profitMarginPercent = round($profitMarginPercent, 2);
}

I want to print, for example, -50% if $vendorTotal is greater than $clientTotal or +50% if the other way round.
This works but with some exceptions:

If $clientTotal is 0.00000 and $vendorTotal is any positive number, e.g. 14.72, my code prints +-100.

If the two variables are equal, e.g. 89.64110, my code prints -0.


Can you explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Bad at math? (0 - 14)/14 becomes -1

Why not simply only add a + whenever $profitMarginPercent is positive?

@KIKOSoftware, I'm trying to figure out how to write this...

Something like this? See: https://3v4l.org/j5BR7 (contains 3x the same code with different values)

@KIKOSoftware, exactly! But not something I would have managed to come up with in such a short time – or at all.

I would go with something like this:
$profitMarginPercent = round((($clientTotal - $vendorTotal + PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON)/$vendorTotal) * 100, 2);
$profitMarginPercent = ($profitMarginPercent > 0.0 ? "+" : "") . $profitMarginPercent;

and then most likely put it in a function or method.
See: https://3v4l.org/j5BR7
What does it do?
As you can see I add PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON to the numerator of the division, this is to prevent a negative result when the numerator and denominator have the same value. It's a very small value, and you round to two decimals, so it never changes the outcome.
Then it adds a + character in front of the number whenever $profitMarginPercent is positive. The - character is already there when the value is negative.

Thank you for explaining! I only noticed that the negative sign was already there after you posted your comment above.

Here is a solution based on sprintf():
function format($val)
{
    if(abs($val) < 1e-6)
        return '0%';
    else
        return sprintf('%+.2f%%', $val);
}

echo format(1.234), PHP_EOL;
echo format(1e-8), PHP_EOL;
echo format(-1.234), PHP_EOL;

Output:
+1.23%
0%
-1.23%

Small values are considered equal to zero.

Yes, sprinft() is a better idea than adding a + oneself.

Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid I'm not that good at math (as someone above pointed out politely) to understand it without explanation how to use this in my particular case.

@cheeseus There is no math here, just formatting. You want to format a percentage, right?

@Olivier, yes, I first want to calculate it, then format it (print + or - in front of it), while rounding it.

@cheeseus Well, this function does the formatting part. I modified it to add the % sign. Call it with $profitMarginPercent.

@Olivier: There is some math in there when I get the code right, at least floating point math: 1e-6 is in there as a magic number and already code-wise I'd suggest to document its meaning in the answer. Otherwise I'm also with KIKO, sprintf() is the better function to format. And, to better show that, $val could be folded to 0 and then perhaps the function could work with the single call point to sprintf and the single return point.
